# Can some1 help me with SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

List the choice of another list after each visit to X if X
included in the original list.

For example, [1,2,1,5,3], X=1, [0,7,9]-> [1,0,7,9,2,1,0,7,9,5,3]

I did some code, but it's not working...

```
insert([], _, [], []) :- !.
insert([H|T], X, Sub, [Res]) :-
   H =\= X, !.
insert([X|T], X, Sub, [Res]) :-
   insert(T, X, Sub, [X|Sub]).
```

Comment: Please do not use images, instead, insert sample runs as text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's working code:

```
insert([], _, [], []) :- !.
insert([], X, Sub, Res) :- !.
insert([H|T], X, Sub, Res) :-
   not(Res = []),
   H = X,
   insert(T, X, Sub, [Res|[H|Sub]]).
insert([H|T], X, Sub, Res) :-
   Res = [],
   H = X,
   insert(T, X, Sub, [H|Sub]). 
insert([H|T], X, Sub, Res) :-
   Res = [],
   member(X,T),
   insert(T, X, Sub, H).   
insert([H|T], X, Sub, Res) :-
   member(X,T),
   insert(T, X, Sub, [Res|[H]]).
insert(List, X, Sub, Res) :-
   insert([], X, Sub, [Res|List]),
   append(Res, List, Z),
   flatten(Z, Result),
   writeln(Result).
```